# How do I access exported enums in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

**so I have declared my enums like so:**

```
export const DOCUMENT_TYPE = { 
    Project: 'Project', 
    Document: 'Document'
}
```

**And now I'm trying to access them in another document:**

```
import DOCUMENT_TYPE from '../constants/enums'

const CreateDocumentScreen = props => {

const type = props.type == DOCUMENT_TYPE.Project ? "Project" : "Document";

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Create {type}</Text>
            <TextInput/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**However, this line:**

```
const type = props.type == DOCUMENT_TYPE.Project ? "Project" : "Document";
```

is throwing `"TypeError: undefined is not an object"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Guess:

```
import { DOCUMENT_TYPE } from '../constants/enums'
```

instead of

```
import DOCUMENT_TYPE from '../constants/enums'
```